# Set up Failover WAN with Double NAT (SonicWall)

Tags: firewall, wan, sonicwall, failover

I am trying to set up failover WAN on a SonicWall TZ300. My primary cable connection comes in via static IP (modem is bridged) to interface X1. My cellular backup is also a static IP to interface X2 (modem is not and cannot be bridged).

My firewall's local IP is 192.168.168.168. I set the cellular backup ethernet to 192.168.167.1/24 and set my X2 interface to static of 192.168.167.2 with a default gateway of 192.168.167.1.

My cellular backup has internet connectivity when I connect to it directly, but when my primary cable internet goes out, I lose internet connectivity on my network.

I wanted to make sure my network is set up correctly to determine if it's a firewall configuration issue.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include a better network description (a diagram would be best), the network device models and configurations, and any logs, debugs, etc. that show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple misconfiguration on my secondary modem/router. I had to define its gateway address as 192.168.167.1 so that my firewall could connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

i was going through your query.
First thing is that what is your failover rule for gateway 1 && gateway 2.
FOr both you can put a simple condition of ping to google,then the gateway failover time limit,while configuring the setting you have to keep in mind,
in which port you are configuring.
as per my knowledge fail-over rules only play some role in these.